"Connection reset by peer" error in WebSocket FastAPI app
I’m working on a WebSocket app with FastAPI and could use some help troubleshooting an issue. So the app allows clients to connect to the WebSocket server and send parameters and based on these parameters, the server sends data to the clients every second from a Kafka topic.
The app works as expected for some time, but eventually, it crashes with a "Connection reset by peer" error. I’m not sure what’s causing this. Is it a client-side issue, or something with my WebSocket implementation?
Any advice on debugging or resolving this would be greatly appreciated!
This is the code for defining the app:
import asyncio
from contextlib import asynccontextmanager
import uvicorn
from fastapi import FastAPI, WebSocket
import src.config as config
from src.handler import CONNECTION_HANDLER
from src.listener.dk import receive_data


current_candles = {}
connection_handler = CONNECTION_HANDLER[config.BROKER](current_candles=current_candles)


@asynccontextmanager
async def lifespan(app: FastAPI):
    # Startup event
    asyncio.create_task(receive_data(current_candles, connection_handler))
    yield
    config.logger.info("Shutting down the application...")


app = FastAPI(lifespan=lifespan)


@app.websocket(config.ROOT_PATH[config.BROKER])
async def websocket_server(ws: WebSocket) -> None:
    """Run WebSocket server to receive clients and send data to them."""

    await ws.accept()
    await connection_handler.connect(ws)


def run_app():
    config.logger.info(f"Streaming data from: {config.BROKER}")
    uvicorn.run(
        app,
        host=config.HOST,
        port=int(config.PORT),
        root_path=config.ROOT_PATH[config.BROKER],
    )

The connect method is defined as follow:
async def connect(self, websocket: WebSocket):
        config.logger.info(f"Received connection from {websocket.client} .")
        message = await websocket.receive_text()
        valid_conn = await self.verif_params(websocket, message)
        if valid_conn:
            logger.info(f"Parameters validated.")
            tokens, symbols, timeframes = self.get_data(message)
            client, _ = await self.add_client(websocket, tokens, symbols, timeframes)
            config.logger.info(f"Client {websocket.client} added for tokens {tokens}.")
            while True:
                try:
                    # Attempt to receive a message to detect if the connection is closed
                    await websocket.receive_text()
                except WebSocketDisconnect:
                    break
            await self.remove_client(client)
            logger.info(f"Client {websocket.client} removed.")
        else:
            config.logger.info(f"Parameters invalid, connection closed.")
            await websocket.close(code=1008)

This is the error that I received:
2024-12-16 10:00:56,060 - ERROR - ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(104, 'Connection reset by peer'))
Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished name='Task-3' coro=<receive_data() done, defined at /app/src/listener/dk.py:52> exception=ConnectError('[Errno 111] Connection refused')>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/httpx/_transports/default.py", line 72, in map_httpcore_exceptions
    yield
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/httpx/_transports/default.py", line 236, in handle_request
    resp = self._pool.handle_request(req)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/httpcore/_sync/connection_pool.py", line 256, in handle_request
    raise exc from None
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/httpcore/_sync/connection_pool.py", line 236, in handle_request
    response = connection.handle_request(
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/httpcore/_sync/connection.py", line 101, in handle_request
    raise exc
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/httpcore/_sync/connection.py", line 78, in handle_request
    stream = self._connect(request)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/httpcore/_sync/connection.py", line 124, in _connect
    stream = self._network_backend.connect_tcp(**kwargs)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/httpcore/_backends/sync.py", line 207, in connect_tcp
    with map_exceptions(exc_map):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/contextlib.py", line 158, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(value)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/httpcore/_exceptions.py", line 14, in map_exceptions
    raise to_exc(exc) from exc
httpcore.ConnectError: [Errno 111] Connection refused

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/src/listener/dk.py", line 55, in receive_data
    kafka_handler = init_kafka_handler()
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/app/src/listener/dk.py", line 30, in init_kafka_handler
    kafka_handler.load_schema()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/feature_store/common/kafka.py", line 170, in load_schema
    _schema = schema_client.get_schema(name)
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/schema_registry/client/client.py", line 518, in get_schema
    result, code = get_response_and_status_code(self.request(url, method=method, headers=headers, timeout=timeout))
                                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/schema_registry/client/client.py", line 295, in request
    response = client.request(method, url, headers=_headers, json=body, params=params, timeout=timeout)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/httpx/_client.py", line 837, in request
    return self.send(request, auth=auth, follow_redirects=follow_redirects)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/httpx/_client.py", line 926, in send
    response = self._send_handling_auth(
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/httpx/_client.py", line 954, in _send_handling_auth
    response = self._send_handling_redirects(
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/httpx/_client.py", line 991, in _send_handling_redirects
    response = self._send_single_request(request)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/httpx/_client.py", line 1027, in _send_single_request
    response = transport.handle_request(request)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/httpx/_transports/default.py", line 235, in handle_request
    with map_httpcore_exceptions():
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/contextlib.py", line 158, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(value)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/httpx/_transports/default.py", line 89, in map_httpcore_exceptions
    raise mapped_exc(message) from exc
httpx.ConnectError: [Errno 111] Connection refused

